# accesing a special character JS file using <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I'm looking for a way to access a JS file, this file contain a script for a multilanguage help system, its works fine until I try accesing a special character like "ñ" or "ê".

This is the file what i want to access:

```
http://bailactms.com/pascual/inc/lang/help_español.js
```

as you can see if you click it it shows a 404 error message, i can access it using an include (PHP) only.

This is my attempt to access it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/lang/help_<?php echo ($_SESSION['tms_lang'])?utf8_decode($_SESSION['tms_lang']):"english"; ?>.js"></script>
```

Note: Its a linux server.

How can I access a special char js file?

Thank you

Comment: Quick-fix: rename the file (if it is yours).

Comment: *How* do you want to access it? Create a link in HTML? Write a shell script? Btw, I would generally recommend *never* to use non-ASCII characters in file names. Doesn't have any advantages, and only causes a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thank you, sadly i can't change that name.
I want to access it using a HTML link, just like the second code what I posted

Comment: Don’t use `utf8_decode`, and if your page isn’t already in UTF-8 (i.e. a `Content-Type` of `text/html; charset=utf-8` or a `<meta charset="utf-8" />`), then make it so.

Comment: And fix its name, because an ASCII `0xf1` is bad. http://bailactms.com/pascual/inc/lang/help_espa%C3%B1ol.js should be the working link. If you can’t, though, Will’s answer is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute %F1 for ñ "spanish n" (url encoded character).
I found the URL encoding from this site:  http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

The URL to the JS file to src is:
http://bailactms.com/pascual/inc/lang/help_espa%F1ol.js

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know a way to convert chars like ñ into %F1 using PHP?

Comment: No problem.  Sorry I don't know enough php!  Maybe google around or ask this as a new question?  Cheers!